# How can I remove filter operators from kendo mvc grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-mvc

I have a kendo mvc grid with a datetime column.

The filters for "is greater than" or "is smaller than" does work on the datetime cell values but NOT the "is equal to" filter.

I want to remove the isequal filter therefore.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use  [filterable.operators.string option](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-filterable.operators.string)

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name" }
  ],
  dataSource: [
    { name: "Jane Doe" },
    { name: "John Doe" }
  ],
  filterable: {
    operators: {
      string: {
        eq: "Equal to",
        neq: "Not equal to"
      }
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Using MVC wrapper you can use:

```
.Filterable(filterable => filterable
    .Extra(false)
     .Operators(operators => operators
        .ForString(str => str.Clear()
            .StartsWith("Starts with")
            .IsEqualTo("Is equal to")
            .IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to")
        ))
    )
```

Comment: so by doing .FilterName I can add the filters I want?

Comment: Yes, but only this filters will appear on the list because you do `.Clear()`

Comment: I do not want to deliver my own localisations. Can I not just say .StartsWith() why do I give it a text?

Comment: I don't know any other good solution. Of course you can always use css to just hide this items (but it is hard to select specific element for this case) or using js

Comment: The I wanna do this because "is equal to" does not work with datetime I guess as my dates have another time... as the datetime set in the datepicker.

Comment: This is not the answer for the above question